# jQuery slideDown jumping effect

Tags: jquery, css, animation, firefox4, slidedown

What is causing this strange jumping effect in FF4 (see sliding down latest jobs)?

http://jsfiddle.net/ipavelek/2dMNb/2/

Everyhing works fine in Chrome/Safari.

Note:
Setting height for `.media` to 45px fixes this particular case, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's probably simply the rendering the browser uses. Is your FF4 slow anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem with jQuery `slideDown` in Firefox. I also think the issue is with calculating the text dimensions. I added this to element:

```
.element_to_slide {
   width: 100%;
}
```

You would not normally need that if your wrapping div has `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:visible` or something else to force element to expand to whole width.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I only came out wit JavaScript solutions. This one looks to be the one solving this problem in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I was able to eliminate the issue by adding a width to the .body class: http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/HBmuv/

Not sure why it's happening, but my guess is that jQuery is calculating the height for the slide animate before FF has figured out that the .body node will fit next to the img anchor.

Comment: The point of this media block is that it should work with any width depending on the parent container, so setting it to 250px (or any other fixed size) doesn't solve the problem. The only solution so far was setting the height or width dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's happening either, but if you check this example http://jsfiddle.net/2dMNb/16/ (I added some backgrounds), you see how the elements behave.